# Slow MSSQL stored procedure in processes excel files with only 30,000 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web applciation with an iterface that users can uplaod files on. The data form the excel file is collected, concatenated and passed to 
a stored procedure which process and returns data.
A brief explanation of the stored procedure.

The stored Procedure collects the string, break it down using a delimeter and stores it in a temp variable table.

Another process is run trough the temp table, where a count is done to find the exact match count and approximate match count by comparing each string 
agains a view which contains
all the names to compare against for each row in the first

An exact match count is where the eact string is found in the view for example.. (Bobby Bolonski )
An approximate match is done using a levenshtein distance algorithm database function with a frequency of 2.
temo table @temp1.

The result (name, exactmatch count and approximate match count) are stored in the final temp table.

a select statement is run on the last temp table to return all the data to the application..

MY problem is that, when i passed huge files like and excel file with 27000 names. IT took like 2 hours to process and return data from the database.

I have checked both servers where the application is on and where the database is on.
On the application server. Both memory and cpu usage are less than 15 %
On the database server. both memory and cpu usage are also less than 15 %.

Am looking for advice on what improvements i can do to make the process faster.

Below is the copy of the stored procedure as it is doing all the work and returning the results to the web application.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindMatch]
    @fullname varchar(max),@frequency int,
    @delimeter varchar(max) AS    

    set @frequency = 2

    declare @transID bigint

    SELECT @transID = ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(5)) AS Bigint)) 

    DECLARE @exactMatch int = 99
    DECLARE @approximateMatch int = 99
    declare @name varchar(50)
    DECLARE @TEMP1 TABLE (fullname varchar(max),approxMatch varchar(max), exactmatch varchar(max))

    DECLARE @ID varchar(max)

    --declare a temp table
     DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (ID int ,fullname varchar(max),approxMatch varchar(max), exactmatch varchar(max))
     --split and store the result in the @temp table
     insert into @TEMP (ID,fullname) select * from fnSplitTest(@fullname, @delimeter)

     --loop trough the @temp table
     WHILE EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM @TEMP)
     BEGIN
        SELECT Top 1 @ID = ID FROM @TEMP 
        select @name = fullname from @TEMP where id = @ID 


          --get the exact match count of the first row from the @temp table and so on until the loop ends
          select @exactMatch = count(1) from  getalldata where  replace(name,',','') COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI =  @name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI

        --declare temp @TEMP3
        DECLARE @TEMP3 TABLE (name varchar(max))


        --insert into @temp 3 only the data that are similar to our search name so as not to loop over all the data in the view
        INSERT INTO @TEMP3(name) 
        select  name from getalldata where  SOUNDEX(name) LIKE SOUNDEX(@name) 

        --get the approximate count using the [DEMLEV] function. 
        --this function uses the Damerau levenshtein distance algorithm to calculate the distinct between the search string
        --and the names inserted into @temp3 above. Uses frequency 2 so as to eliminate all the others
        select @approximateMatch = count(1) from @TEMP3 where
        dbo.[DamLev](replace(name,',',''),@name,@frequency) <= @frequency and 
        dbo.[DamLev](replace(name,',',''),@name,@frequency) > 0  and name != @name


        --insert into @temp1 at end of every loop results
          insert into  @TEMP1 (fullname,approxMatch, exactmatch) values(@name,@approximateMatch,@exactMatch)
        insert into FileUploadNameInsert (name) values (@name + ' ' +cast(@approximateMatch as varchar) + ' ' + cast(@exactMatch as varchar) + ', ' + cast(@transID as varchar)  )
        DELETE FROM @TEMP WHERE ID= @ID
        delete from @TEMP3
    END

    --Return all the data stored in @temp3
    select fullname,exactmatch,approxMatch, @transID as transactionID from @TEMP1

GO
```

Comment: Can you dump the code of fnSplitTest? Excel sheet is csv or xls extension, how to load it?

Comment: First off you need to find the culprit which is slowing down the application. Is it importing CSV, Inserting data to Temp Table or Processing Records. Processing Records is fairly straight forward. I would still recommend cte's but that is the next step.

Comment: have you looked at your execution plan, those replaces and your functions  and like statements, and temp tabes look pretty scary

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,

1. Use Openrowset to directly read the records into a pre-defined, properly indexed table of your database.
2. Now, perform your operations using this table at back-end using pre-defined Stored Procedures.

It should take around 15 minutes for 30,000 rows.